# Asp.net jquery ajax call

Tags: asp.net, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am practicing jquery ajax call. What happens is when i run my project it gives INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 500. What does this error means and how do I encounter this error?

I created a sample project in which i added this code:

```
   namespace sample
{
    public partial class jqAjaxcall : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                GetDateTime();
        }
        [WebMethod]
        private static string GetDateTime()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

My aspx code file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Library/js/jquery-1.9.1-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
            $("#Result").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "jqAjaxcall.aspx/GetDateTime",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                        $("#Result").text(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="Result">
        Click here for the time.</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Your Function Public...to Access from Jquery like this

```
 [WebMethod]
//define function as public....
        public static string GetDateTime()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
```